# Как отображать маркеры видимиые только на экране.?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-api

Есть приложение и там 1000 маркеров. Хочу показать только те, что на экране.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У гугл карты есть метод  `map.getBounds()` который вам возвращает рамки видимой части карты.

Из bounds можно достать координаты верхнего левого и нижнего правого углов.

Проверяете какие из маркеров лежат в видимой области сравнивая по координатам и рисуете необходимые.

Так же у карты есть коллбеки

```
OnCameraMoveStartedListener,
    OnCameraMoveListener,
    OnCameraMoveCanceledListener,
```

Подробнее про них в [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events)

Собственно там есть коллбек`onCameraMove()` в нём и запускайте свои проверки. Но не уверен что пересчеты при каждом движении камеры будут оптимальнее чем один раз отрисовать все маркеры

Comment: Пересчитывать нужно не при каждом движении, а при каждой остановке камеры. И это будет гораздо оптимальней чем отрисовка всех маркеров сразу.

Comment: @eugeneek спасибо за уточнение